# Queue Build in TFS 2015 REST API with PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, tfs

I'm trying to queue a build using the REST API with on-premises TFS 2015.2 using PowerShell.

```
$body @{ id = 1 }

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Credential "myusername" -ContentType application/json -Uri "https://{tfsurl}/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)
```

It throws an error that it needs the definition which needs to be in the JSON. PowerShell doesn't like this, so am I missing a simple syntax error?

```
$body = @{
"definition": {
    "id":1
 }
}
```

I saw this post: [How to trigger a build in TFS 2015 using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376206/how-to-trigger-a-build-in-tfs-2015-using-rest-api) but I don't think it helps much with the PowerShell side of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you the JSON you need:

```
$body = @{ definition = @{id = 1} }
```