# How do I queue a new build in Visual Studio without the options popup?

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

I know I can set up continuous integration - and that makes builds happen seamlessly. However this isn't appropriate for all our projects.

So for those, I can right-click the build and select queue new build and wait for the popup and queue it.

However, I never have to change those options. And this is about more than saving a click. More than once I've right-clicked and selected Queue build, left my desk before it appears (sometimes it takes 5-8 sec), meaning to meet with a co-worker or take lunch break prior to a large build.

Then I return to my desk and unlock my PC only to be greeted by the 'queue build' popup. Then I have to wait for it to build.

Usually I remember ... but the times I get burned are bitter indeed!

Comment: Which tfs build are you using the old XAML build or the new vNext build?

Comment: Old XAML build thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to suppress the options pop up when you queue the build either in visual-studio or web. For vNext build, it will also open a web portal.

As a workaround, you could try to use TFS API or Rest API to trigger the build instead of manually through Visual Studio. Please follow below tutorials:

- For vNext Build:
  [How to trigger a build in TFS 2015 using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376206/how-to-trigger-a-build-in-tfs-2015-using-rest-api)
- For XAML Build: [TFS API Queue a New Build with Custom Parameters](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801629/TFS-API-Queue-a-New-Build-with-Custom-Parameters)

Besides you could also add a use voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) , TFS PM and Admin will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: Since I often don't even have the same team project open (projects are shared across solutions), I can use this method to make a few shortcuts to do the builds - also saving me the time of switching projects and clicking the favorite - so this is even better! Although a bit more work.

Comment: I can't think of how I'd implement this ... maybe I'll just suggest a 'queue new build using defaults' in the rightclick? thanks for the great answer.